# Inexperienced Ubuntu user trying to set up internet connection on laptop with 13.04

Tags: wireless, 13.04, internet

I haven't installed 13.04 yet, but I need to know how to access internet before I install. Can I get instructions? Wireless will be my main form of connection.

Comment: Most WiFi hardware work out of the box or minimal set up. Could you clarify what wireless card/device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up BEFORE installing so no worries there.

- Check your router and take note of your passphrase and encryption details (Ubuntu does not work with WEP anymore since that is broken by design; make sure it is WPA2). You need the password later.
- Use "try Ubuntu" before "install Ubuntu";
- Select your wireless;
- Insert and save password;
- When it connects Ubuntu use the "install Ubuntu" shortcut to start installing. The installer can then also fetch packages from the web for the 3rd party extras (like mp3 support) and/or upgraded software.

In the rare case it does not find your network or does not pick up your card you can still stop the installation and first check out why this is. You will need your wireless card details (brand, chipset etc) and search for it on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forum.php) or the [Ubuntu WIKI](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/) in case it is hardware related.

Since you said "main" form of connection: of course you can also use a wired connection after installation to fix a wireless network problem. You only need to do this one time and only if the wireless connection gives problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu 13.04 via Live DVD/CD it should be able to detect your wireless card automatically and you should be able to see a notification letting you know that there is wireless connections available, are you not seeing this if running Ubuntu via Live CD/DVD?

Luis